# .log to .csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a .log file in the below format :

```
A1 B1 C1 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
```

I want to make a .csv out of it as :

```
A  B  C  D #columnname
A1 B1 C1 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
```

Note : Without using Pandas & Numpy

Comment: Look at the `csv` module.

Comment: What is the rule to add the `A B C D`?

Comment: A B C D , is just the column name.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/bin/python
with open('log', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = data.split()
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
data = columns + data

toSave = ''
j=1
for i in range(len(data)):
   if (j % 5 == 0):
       toSave = toSave + '\n' + data[i] + ' '
       j=1
   else:
       toSave = toSave + data[i] + ' '
   j+=1

f = open("log.csv", "w")
f.write(toSave)
f.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).